# what is the best way to handle variable names in python if the all the variables need to have a float(decimal) in it?

Tags: python, function, variables, dataset

Totally new in this forum and new in python so I would appreciate it if anybody can help me.

I am trying to build a script in python based on data that I have in an excel spreadsheet. I'd like to create an app/script where I can estimate the pregnancy due date and the conception date (for animals) based on measurements that I have taken during ultrasounds. I am able to estimate it with a calculator but it takes some conversion to do (from cm to mm) and days to months. In order to do that in Python, I figured I create a variable for each measurement and set each variable equals to its value in days (and integer).

**Here is the problem**: the main column of my data set is the actual measurements of the babies in mm (Known as BPD) but the BPD can be an integer like 5mm or 6.4mm. Since I can't name a variable with a period or a dot in it, what would be the best way to handle my data and assign variables to it? I have tried BPD_4.8= 77days, but python tells me there's a syntax error (I'm sure lol), but if I type BDP_5= 78 it seems to work.  I haven't mastered lists and tuples, not do I really know how to use them properly so ill keep looking online and see what happens.

I'm sure it's something super silly for you guys, but I'm really pulling my hair out and I have nothing but 2 inches of hair lol

[This is what my current screen looks like..HELP :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0PKa.png)

Comment: Just choose a valid name.... But you probably should be using  some container for this(like a `dict`), not a bunch of variables

Comment: It *really* sounds like you should be using a dictionary instead of a bunch of variables.

Comment: Note, variable names **never** need to have anything in them. Variable names are a matter of source code, they are for what *humans read*

Answer (score 1):

Howdy and welcome to StackOverflow. The short answer is:

**Use a better data structure**

You really shouldn't be encoding valuable information into variable names like that. What's going to happen if you want to calculate something with your BPD measurements? Or when you have duplicate BPD's?

This is bad practise. It might seem like a lot of effort to take the time to figure out how to do this properly - but it will be more than worth it if you intend to continue to use Python :)

I'll give you a couple options...

**Option 1: Use a dictionary**

Dictionaries are common data structures in any language.. so it can pay to know how to use them.

Dictionaries hold information about an object using key/value pairs. For example you might have:

```py
measurements = {
    'animal_1' : {'bpd': 4.6, 'due_date_days': 55},
    'animal_2' : {'bpd': 5.2, 'due_date_days': 77},
    }
```

An advantage of dictionaries is that they are explicit, ie values have keys which explicitly identify what the information is assigned to. E.g. `measurements['animal_1']['due_date_days']` would return the due date for animal 1.

A disadvantage is that it will be harder to compute information / examine relationships than you'll be used to in Excel.

**Option 2: Use Pandas**

Pandas is a data science library for Python. It's fast, has similar functionality to Excel and is probably well suited to your use case.

I'd recommend you take the time to do a tutorial or two. If you're planning to use Python for data analysis then it's worth using the language and any suitable libraries properly.

You can check out some Pandas tutorials here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html

Good luck!